# Force sequential execution in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We have a stored procedure that executes a number of selects and updates on various tables.  This stored procedure is being called within an SSIS package.  It is only called once.  I can see in the execution plan (and in my trace) that the queries are executing in parallel.  This isn't an issue when volume is low but when data volume is high, the statements are causing deadlocks and the package fails due to deadlock.  I thought to Set the lock timeout in the SP but I'd prefer to force sequential execution of the updates if possible.  Any help suggestions on how to force sequential execution within the stored procedure would be a great help.

Comment: Are you talking about parallel execution of stored procedure on CPU, if this is the case i would recommend you to use OPTION(MAXDOP 1) query option inside procedure causing for parallelism.

Comment: Inside the SP there are multiple updates on several tables.  On 2 tables there are probably 8 updates each.  I can see from the execution plan for the SP that SQL Server is executing the updates in parallel and this is causing deadlocks when data volume is high.